# AngularJS remove last element of array in scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have my controller in Angular which contains an array and a delete method

```
function($scope, $http){
    $scope.arrayOfObjects = [];
    $scope.remove = function(obj){
        var i = $scope.arrayOfObjects.indexOf(obj);
        if( i > -1 ){
            $scope.arrayOfObjects.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
// Some other things
}
```

HTML

```
<a href ng-repeat="(key, obj) in arrayOfObjects track by $index">{{obj.id}}

<button type="button" role="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="remove(obj)">
   <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
   <span>Delete</span>
</button>

</a>
```

Now all works well when I delete an object other than the last. When the user presses on the delete button for the last object, the page gets redirected to localhost:3000/# which is not mapped to anything and I get a blank page.

Has anyone encountered such behavior?

Comment: Why is your button inside the `<a>` tag? I would.. do something more like `<div ng-repeat".."><a>Link</a><button>Delete</button></div>`

Comment: better use a button for those tasks, if you are using anchor tag, make sure 
href="javascript:;"

Comment: azium, you are correct. Took the <a> out and now everything is working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers are addressing your link / redirect issue, which would be solved by not having additional clickable items inside an anchor tag, the bigger problem is that you're using the wrong syntax for iterating over the objects of an array.

To iterate over an array you want this:

```
ng-repeat="obj in arrayOfObjects"
```

The syntax you're using is for iterating over the properties of one single object. Where `key` and `value` are the arguments passed to your repeater

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in object"
```

Most likely what you want is something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in arrayOfObjects">
  {{obj.id}}
  <button ng-click="remove(obj)">Delete</button>
</div>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/XbMYrL?editors=101)

Comment: Do you have any references of why the syntax I am using is not correct? Given that I have `track by $index`, `key` is giving me the index of the element in the array, which I see situations where this is useful.

Comment: Well there's the documentation of course https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat. The thing is that arrays are objects as well so it might look like it's working, but not in the way you're expecting. All types in JavaScript (and a bunch of other languages too) inherit from Object, but yea you're confusing Angular by using object property iteration syntax on an array.

Comment: You can get the index of an element with `$index`....  `<div ng-repeat="element in array">{{$index}} - {{element}}</div>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'filter' to return to original scope all itens that you want, just like that:

```
        $scope.remove = function (objs) {
            $scope.objs = objs.filter(function (obj) {
               //Here you remove the item you do not want   
               return obj;
            });
        };
```

Html:

```
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" ng-click="remove(objs)">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Last element can be removed by using `pop()` and returns that element like `$scope.arrayOfObjects.pop()`

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('mycontroller', function($scope) {
  $scope.arrayOfObjects = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mycontroller">
  <button ng-click="arrayOfObjects.pop()">remove in inline</button>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="myobj in arrayOfObjects">{{myobj.id}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```